# Quasi-hereditary covers

Tags: rt.representation-theory

What is the quasi-hereditary cover of a quasi-hereditary algebra?

Is the algebra A somehow (always) a quasi-hereditary cover of itself?  Or is their a relation to Ringel duality in some way?

Comment: Do you already know R. Rouquier, *q-Schur algebras and complex reflection groups*?

Comment: Yes, any quasi-hereditary algebra is a cover of itself tautologically.  Ringel duality has nothing to do with it.  

Comment: Thanks Ben (and Martin) that's what I thought it should be - very helpful.  I'd like to give you the "reputation points" but don't understand how this works.